# Django Like button directing to This page isn’t working

Tags: python, django

I have tried another method to create a like button for posts, I have reached to the phase where button directs me to an error of `This page isn’t working`

Not sure where the problem relies on. I am following a tutorial but the only difference is that the tutorial created a function for the post with context in the views while I created a class for the post. I don't know if this is the reason for some deviations and the error appearing

Here is the Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     ---- Others unrelated models------ 
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='liked')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("score:post-detail", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    @property
    def num_likes(self):
        return self.liked.all().count()

LIKE_CHOICES = (
    ('Like', 'Like'),
    ('Unlike', 'Unlike'),
)

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(choices=LIKE_CHOICES,
                             default='Like', max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.post)
```

here is the views

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "score.html"
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True)
    paginate_by = 5

def like_post(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'Post':
        post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
        post_obj = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)

        if user in post_obj.liked.all():
            post.obj.liked.remove(user)
        else:
            post_obj.liked.add(user)

        like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=user, post_id=post_id)

        if not created:
            if like.value == 'Like':
                like.value = 'Unlike'
            else:
                like.value = 'Like'
        like.save()
    return redirect('score:like_post')
```

here is the full template

```
{% extends "base.html"%}

        {% block content %}
            {% for post in posts %}

                        <div style="padding-top:200 px"><strong>{{post.title}}</strong></div>


                        <form action="{% url 'score:like_post'%}" method='POST' class="ui form">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type='hidden' name='post_id' value="{{post.id}}">
                            {% if user not in post.liked.all %}
                                <button class= "ui button positive" type='submit'> Like </button>
                            {% else %}
                                <button class= "ui button negative" type='submit'> Unlike </button>
                            {% endif %}
                        </form>
                        <strong>{{post.liked.all.count}} Likes </strong>

            {% endfor %}

        {% endblock content %}
```

and here is the URL

```
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='score'),
    path('like/', like_post, name='like_post'),
```

here is the base

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>
    {% block extra_head %}
    {% endblock %}

</head>

<body>

    <!--Main layout-->
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock %}
    <!--Main layout-->

    <!--Footer-->
{% include "footer.html" %}
    <!--/.Footer-->

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
{% include "scripts.html" %}

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    {% block extra_scripts %}
    {% endblock extra_scripts %}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you importing your `views` in `urls.py`? It's normally written as `views.like_post`. Can you also update your `base.html`.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 yes I imported it in the url `from .views import (PostCreateView, PostDeleteView, PostDetailView,
                    PostListView, PostUpdateView, UserPostListView, like_post)`  Update the base with what ?

Comment: Add the code of the base.html to the post.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 done but what has the base got to do with the issue ?

Comment: @PruthviBarot when i indent it and add to to the class scope it disconnects the server `ImportError: cannot import name 'like_post' from 'score.views'`

Comment: A similar problem stated that it was caused by `block statement` in the template. So just confirming it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a result of infinite recursion, i.e. when you click on the like button it redirects you to `views.like_post`, which again redirects to itself. Therefore, causing an infinite redirection issue. You can fix this by redirecting to some other view or go with an initial implementation shown in your tutorial.

Since any view in Django must return an `HTTPRESPONSE`, you can just return this

```
return HttpResponse("OK")
```

Comment: I have added return HttpResponse("OK") and it was successful also I replaced it with      `return redirect('score:like_post')`, but the buttons are not changing from like to unlike I don't think anything action is taking place

Comment: Buttons changes should be handled by Javascript. So you need to check what's going on when you handle the response.

Comment: no likes have been recorded as I checked in the admin

Comment: Well, if your view function executes, which it does then it should be updated. Given this `tutorial created a function for the post with context in the views while I created a class for the post.` it may also be happening due to the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
def like_post(request):
    user = request.user
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
        post_obj = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)

        if user in post_obj.likes.all():
            post_obj.likes.remove(user)
        else:
            post_obj.likes.add(user)

        like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=user, post_id=post_id)

        if not created:
            if like.value == 'Like':
                like.value = 'Unlike'
            else:
                like.value = 'Like'
        like.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
```

Instead of redirect you can use HttpResponseRedirect and don't forget to import it from django.http